# SQL Server error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write this code, but I keep getting this error. `AUSVN` and `AUZTV` columns are of type `nvarchar`. Please help me.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, AUSVN)) + ' ' + (LEFT(AUZTV, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(AUZTV, 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(AUZTV, 2))))  
FROM 
    VIQMEL
```

`AUSVN` column has values like `2018-04-27 14:20:18.000`.

Comment: Sample data is going to greatly help here. We can't see your data, so we have no way of answering this question

Comment: what format is data stored? YYYY-MM-DD ? or DD-MM-YYYY ?

Comment: If 2012+ use try_convert().   It will return a NULL if the conversion fails.  To identify the problem records  Select * from YourTable where try_convert(date,AUZTV) is null

Comment: If you store the date as parts, use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to construct the date value instead of creating a string and trying to parse it. Otherwise use the *correct* data types instead of strings - `date` for dates and `time` for time of day

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, but DATEFROMPARTS is not usefull for me.

Comment: You need to give exact samples of both `AUSVN` and `AUZTV`. And multiple samples is lots better than one. Also mention outliers such as `''` or `NULL`.

Comment: do all rows fail?  does it still fail if you do a SELECT Top 1..etc?  If there is a rogue row that is failing, it may simply be an invalid date, such as select cast('2100-02-29 14:20:18.000' as datetime2) for example, will give you the error, although the format may seem correct at first glance (or any other date/time that is not such)

Comment: @Mg45, for future reference, in case it isn't clear from the other comments, your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed if you still need help.

Comment: I do not know if the solution is on this side, but I recommend turning it into "datetime2", which is considered an extension of "datetime". The MSDN documentation for datetime recommends using datetime2. Here is their recommendation:

Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision. datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed applications.

Comment: @Whencesoever, data format is YYYY-MM-DD,

Comment: @EricBrandt thank you for your information, I will explain this error.

Comment: @Cato hi, yes I get error all rows and I tried 'select top 1... etc'

Comment: what happens if you do          select cast('2018-04-27 14:20:18.000' as datetime) as MyDate                                on the DB you are having trouble with?  If that doesn't work, then it suggests that date and time settings on the server or DB you are seeing the problem on has some sort of date time settings that do not like the format you are trying to convert.

Comment: Hi everyone, 
I was joining this table with another table.
Joined column also has special characters , $$.

Comment: Thank you for all your answer.

Comment: oh right so you solved it?  No problems - good luck with your project.

Comment: Yes @Cato, thank you for good your wishes :)